# Delphi Exception error loading remote image

Tags: delphi

Hi I have the following code:

```
procedure TformInvoiceDetails.ReadWebImage(imgAddress: string);
var
  memStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  memStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get (imgAddress,memStream);
    //sleep(5000);
  except
    imageContProduct.Visible := false;
    ShowMessage('Image not found at:'+imgAddress);
    memStream.Free;
    exit;
  end;
  try
    memStream.Position := 0;
    imageContProduct.Visible := true;
    imageContProduct.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(memStream);
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Most of the time it works okay but I keep getting an exeption error and sometimes a 'Image not found at' ( although the image does exist).

If I put the sleep(5000) everything works okay.

So I am presuming the image has not been recived before I try and add to the TImage.

Is there a better method to use ?

Comment: Well, you threw away the diagnostic information in the exception, so,.......

Comment: Access violation at address 01014323 at... read address 00000030

Comment: The error you report in your question "Image not found at..." is your own error message. As pointed out, your exception handler completely ignores the actual exception, and just assumes that your image is not found, when in fact, it  could be something else. Now you mention Access Violation. Is that the exception you actually catch here? Is that exactly where your breakpoint stops when debugging?

Comment: My advice is to spend some time improving your debugging skills

Comment: @Frank "*read address 00000030*" - accessing an address near 0 usually implies that a nil pointer is being used somewhere

Comment: @RemyLebeau It not just can be a NIL value (easy to catch) but an uninitialized pointer like variable as well

Comment: I moved the stream code to the IdHTTP1WorkEnd . From the error log. First chance exception at $01003F25. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x01003f25: read of address 0x00000030'. Process mysqltest2.exe (25972). Is there a way to check the file has actually arrived and downloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use another components to load pictures:

```
uses WinInet, JPEG;
...
function DownloadToStream(Url: string; Stream: TStream): Boolean;
var
  hNet: HINTERNET;
  hUrl: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..10240] of Char;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  hNet := InternetOpen('agent', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if (hNet <> nil) then
  begin
    hUrl := InternetOpenUrl(hNet, PChar(Url), nil, 0,
      INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if (hUrl <> nil) then
    begin
      while (InternetReadFile(hUrl, @Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), BytesRead)) do
      begin
        if (BytesRead = 0) then
        begin
          Result := TRUE;
          break;
        end;
        Stream.WriteBuffer(Buffer,BytesRead);
      end;
      InternetCloseHandle(hUrl);
    end;
    InternetCloseHandle(hNet);
  end;
end;

procedure TformInvoiceDetails.ReadWebImage(imgAddress: string);
var
  memStream: TMemoryStream;
  Jpg:= TJPEGImage;
begin
  memStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if DownloadToStream(imgAddress, memStream) then
    begin
      memStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      if (LowerCase(RightStr(imgAddress, 4))='.jpg') or (LowerCase(RightStr(imgAddress, 5))='.jpeg')
        try //do the same operation for *.png
          Jpg:= TJPEGImage.Create;
          Jpg.LoadFromStream(memStream);
          imageContProduct.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(Jpg);
          imageContProduct.Visible := true;
        finally
          Jpg.Free;
        end
      else
        try
          imageContProduct.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(memStream);
          imageContProduct.Visible := true;
        finally
        end;
    end;
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```